# Easiest way to read Excel files in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

Are there any warappers/utils available to read Excel files in Groovy. I am looking for something similar to Groovy SQL's *rows* function as shown in below spock test example. My intention is to use this for [data driven testing using excel in Spock test framework](http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/DatabaseDrivenSpecification)

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

import spock.lang.*

class DatabaseDriven extends Specification {
  @Shared sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:h2:mem:", "org.h2.Driver")

  // normally an external database would be used,
  // and the test data wouldn't have to be inserted here
  def setupSpec() {
    sql.execute("create table maxdata (id int primary key, a int, b int, c int)")
    sql.execute("insert into maxdata values (1, 3, 7, 7), (2, 5, 4, 5), (3, 9, 9, 9)")
  }

  def "maximum of two numbers"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c

    where:
    [a, b, c] << sql.rows("select a, b, c from maxdata")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of my fellow GUG members has created a tool for working with Excel using Apache POI in very much the same way you describe. It's not formalized into a library yet (AFAIK) but is available on his blog.

It allows you to write code like this:

```
new ExcelBuilder("customers.xls").eachLine([labels:true]) {
  new Person(name:"$firstname $lastname",
    address:address, telephone:phone).save()
}
```

Check it out here: http://www.technipelago.se/content/technipelago/blog/44

Comment: To make things a little easier for people, I turned Goran's code into a github repo.  I also modified it to use Grab for its dependencies, work with xlsx files, and just return Strings for each cell.  Using the cell type was giving me trouble for what I needed to do. 
https://github.com/dtanner/groovy-excel-reader

Answer (score 6):

POI is what your after http://poi.apache.org/ its a Java Lib so you can use it from Groovy. Not sure if there are Groovy wrappers for it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

```
@Grab('org.apache.poi:poi:3.8')
@Grab('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.8')
@GrabExclude('xml-apis:xml-apis')
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
def excelFile = new File('F:/test.xlsx')


excelFile.withInputStream { is ->
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is)
    (0..<workbook.numberOfSheets).each { sheetNumber ->
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt( sheetNumber )
        sheet.rowIterator().each { row ->
            row.cellIterator().each { cell ->
                println cell.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could also recommend use [Groovy Spreadsheet Builder](http://metadataconsulting.github.io/spreadsheet-builder/#_reading_and_querying_spreadsheets). It available in maven repository (contrary to `ExcelBuilder`) and also have expressive Groovy-syntax:

```
SpreadsheetQuery query = PoiSpreadsheetCriteria.FACTORY.forFile(file)                      // <1>

Collection  cells = query.query {
    sheet {                                                                            
        row {                                                                           
            cell {
                value 'B'
            }
        }
    }
}

assert cells.size() == 1
assert cells.first().value == 'B'
```

Or:

```
Collection rows = query.query {
    sheet(name({ name.startsWith('Con') })) {
        row(1)
    }
}.rows
```

Documentation contains many examples.
It even may write Excel files in same way!