# creating XML from spreadsheet using AWK?

Tags: xml, shell, awk, spreadsheet

I have [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0An4-EZ8cgL4udGEzUHpyRjZWcTJKNUJVSk13QzBJQ1E). I would like to generate some xml manifests from it.

Here is a section of the spreadsheet:

[image]

Here is the xml to be generated, with name "mst-5.3_tmp.xml" (filename based off the Section)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<activity type='cxp:jsp'>
<handler>mindtap_mastery</handler>

<!-- Section 5.3 Mastery -->
<group threshold="1" name="Energy and Temperature Change to Specific Heat">
 <items>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32027" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
 </items>
</group>
<group threshold="3" name="Specific Heat to Energy or Temperature">
 <items>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32040" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32041" title="Mastery Item 2"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32046" title="Mastery Item 3"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32048" title="Mastery Item 4"/>
 </items>
</group>
<group threshold="2" name="Thermal Equilibrium">
 <items>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32378" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.32380" title="Mastery Item 2"/>
 </items>
</group>
<group threshold="2" name="Phase Change Energetics">
 <items>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.3737" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.3741" title="Mastery Item 2"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.3752" title="Mastery Item 3"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.3753" title="Mastery Item 4"/>
 </items>
</group>
<group threshold="2" name="Heating Curves - Calculations">
 <items>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.5640" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.5641" title="Mastery Item 2"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.5642" title="Mastery Item 1"/>
  <item src="owms01h/gen.question.5643" title="Mastery Item 2"/>
 </items>
</group>

</activity>
```

My aim is to export the spreadsheet to a tab-separated text file, and create the xml using AWK. When a value exists in the "Section" column, a new file should be created. The adjacent "Instruction Unit column contains the name of the first "group" element. The "items" of this group start with the entry in the adjacent "Geyser Item Name" column. If the next row has no "Section" or "Instructional Unit" values, then it should be added as an item to the current group. If there is an "Instructional Unit" value, but no "Section" then a new group should be created. Etc.

I am unsure how to begin and end new files, and how to have AWK skip columns/lines as described in the control above.

So far, all I have is a script that creates justone file with the nesting close to, but not exactly, what I describe above.

```
 #!/bin/bash

awk -F "\t" '{
    if ($2) {
    print "</items>";
    print "</group>";
    print "</activity>";
    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>"
    print "<activity type='cxp:jsp'>";
    print "<handler>mindtap_mastery</handler>";
    print "<!--" $2 "-->";
    }
    if ($3) {
    print "<group threshold=\"1\" name=\"" $3 "\">";
    print "<items>";
    print "<item src=\"owms01h/" $4  "\" title=\"Mastery Item 1\"/>";
    } else {
    print "<item src=\"owms01h/" $4  "\" title=\"Mastery Item 1\"/>";
    }

}' 'Media Grid_Units 1-5.txt' >> master.xml
```

Comment: I believe answer will change drastically, based on spreadsheet format after downloading - xls/xlsx/odf... Probably, you are downloading it as csv/tab separated format, which is good.

Comment: Yes, I am parsing the data as a tab separated text file.

Comment: Doing this in awk is hard work. Have you considering switching to a scripting language that supports parsing of Excel files directly? For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157114/easiest-way-to-read-excel-files-in-groovy

Comment: I had not looked at Groovy. Thanks! I would still like to figure this out in AWK because I'm stubborn like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save this as `somefile.awk` and call it with `awk -F"\t" -f somefile.awk spreadsheet.tab`

```
NR==1 || !$4 {next} # Skip the header and blank lines

$2 { # New section
    if (printingitems) { # close tags
        print "</items>" >> filename;
        print "</group>" >> filename;
        print "</activity>" >> filename;
    }
    # Build new filename
    split($2, part, " ");
    filename = "mst-"part[2]"_tmp.xml";

    print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>" >> filename;
    print "<activity type='cxp:jsp'>" >> filename;
    print "<handler>mindtap_mastery</handler>" >> filename;
    print "<!--" $2 "-->" >> filename;
    printingitems = 0;
}

$3 { # New group
    if (printingitems) {
    print "</items>" >> filename;
    print "</group>" >> filename; 
    }
    groupname = substr($3, 5, length($3));
    print "<group threshold=\"1\" name=\"" groupname "\">" >> filename;
    print "<items>" >> filename;
    printingitems = 1;
} 

{ # new item
    print "<item src=\"owms01h/" $4  "\" title=\"Mastery Item "printingitems++"\"/>" >> filename;
}

END { # this assumes all non-blank lines will have an item
    print "</items>" >> filename;
    print "</group>" >> filename;
    print "</activity>" >> filename;
}
```